# How to add Recycler view in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

I am not able to use the `RecyclerVeiw` class even after adding dependencies in `build.gradle(Module:app)`

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to add any dependency

```
//in xml
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

// in class
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to add any special dependency
Just update android studio and use it

Even though if you want to make it work through adding dependencies add this

```
//in xml add this
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

// in class add this
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
```